# Is there any way to test and give a True/False statement to see if a file exists, Python

Tags: python, file

Im trying to make lines of code where it checks if a file with a name like "text1.txt" exists in a directory. If it exists it will proceed to run the program, if it doesnt it will do something else.

Comment: Consider os.path.exists

Comment: Have you seen [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pathlib2 library

```
from pathlib2 import Path

if (Path(".") / <YOUR_FILE_NAME_.txt>).exists():
  do your stuff here
```

Assuming you run your python code from your directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os builtin module. Check here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

basically you can try something like this, keep in mind that if the directory containing the file is not the cwd, you will need to provide the full path to the file.

```
import os
os.path.exists('<filename>')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using `pathlib`, you can just use `.exists()` on a Path.